# Are processElement1 and processElement2 from KeyedCoProcessFunction atomic w.r.t. state? or could they modify a shared state concurrently?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 2 streams, one data stream that just contains a flag to set `ValueState` `passing=true/false`, another control stream that adds a user to be notified to `MapState`. When `passing` changes from `false` to `true`, a notification is issued to the users present in `MapState` who have not yet been notified.

Heres how the state transitions

[image]

Here is the `KeyedCoProcessFunction` that handles this logic.

```scala
class TestKeyedCoProcessFunction extends KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, String, String, String] {

    @transient private var notified: MapState[String, Boolean] = _ // user:was_notified
    @transient private var passing: ValueState[java.lang.Boolean] = _ // issue notification when updated to passing=true 

    override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
      val notifiedDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor("notified", Types.STRING, Types.BOOLEAN)
      notified = getRuntimeContext.getMapState(notifiedDescriptor)

      val passingDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor("passing", Types.BOOLEAN)
      passing = getRuntimeContext.getState(passingDescriptor)

      if (passing.value() == null) {
        passing.update(false)
      }
    }

    def addUser(user: String): Boolean = {
      if (notified.contains(user)) {
        false
      } else {
        notified.put(user, false)
        true
      }
    }

    def setPassing(newPassing: String): Boolean = {
      if (passing.value()) {
        if (newPassing == "true") {
          false
        } else {
          passing.update(false)
          true
        }
      } else {
        if (newPassing == "false") {
          false
        } else {
          passing.update(true)
          true
        }
      }
    }

    def notifyNotNotifiedUsers(collector: Collector[String]): Unit = {
      val keys = notified.keys().iterator()
      while (keys.hasNext) {
        val user = keys.next()
        val userNotified = notified.get(user)
        if (!userNotified) {
          collector.collect("Hey " + user + " passing=true")
          notified.put(user, true)
        }
      }
    }

    def setNotifiedFalseAll(): Unit = {
      val keys = notified.keys().iterator()
      while (keys.hasNext) {
        val user = keys.next()
        val userNotified = notified.get(user)
        if (userNotified) {
          notified.put(user, false)
        }
      }
    }

    override def processElement1(user: String,
                                 context: KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, String, String, String]#Context,
                                 collector: Collector[String]): Unit = {
      addUser(user)
      if (passing.value()) {
        notifyNotNotifiedUsers(collector)
      }
    }

    override def processElement2(newPassing: String,
                                 context: KeyedCoProcessFunction[String, String, String, String]#Context,
                                 collector: Collector[String]): Unit = {
      val modified = setPassing(newPassing)
      if (passing.value()) {
        notifyNotNotifiedUsers(collector)
      } else {
        if (modified) {
          setNotifiedFalseAll()
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Is it possible for a race condition to occur in `Flink` where `processElement1` and `processElement2` are being executed simultaneously, for example

```
t+1 processElement2("true")
t+2 processElement2: setPassing("true")
t+3 processElement2: notifyNotNotifiedUsers() // starts iteration on MapState
t+4 processElement1("new_user")
t+5 processElement1: addUser(user) // adds user to MapState
t+6 processElement1: notifyNotNotifiedUsers() // starts another parallel iteration on MapState resulting in maybe missed/duplicate notification
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no possibility of a race condition in any given instance of a `KeyedCoProcessFunction`, or in any of Flink's user function interfaces, for that matter. `processElement1` and `processElement2` can not be executed concurrently. `onTimer` is safe as well.

Comment: Alright no reason to worry then, thanks David, you have been really helpful in my quest to learn Flink